# WIDTH property is not affected to a dialog box in Simple Modal1 jquery plugin

Tags: simplemodal

I've just faced the problem on the SimpleModal1 jquery plugin

I'm studying web programming, and i'm building any pages that I want now.
And I'm using SimpleModal1 plugin, and jquery.modal() works fine.

But... in one of my JS file, giving option **containerCSS:{"width":"20%"}** doesn't affect the  dialog box's horizontal size.

---

## The Problematic JS File

function openLoginDialog(){

```
$("#dialog_login").modal({
    closeHTML:".modalCloseImg",
    
    containerCSS:{
        "width":"20%"
    }
});
```

}

---

## Another file that works fine

function openJoinDialog(){

```
$("#dialog_join").modal({
    closeHTML:".modalCloseImg",
    
    containerCss:{
        "width":"80%",
        "height":"820px"
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

containerCss is not the same as containerCSS... Your problem might just be a simple matter of misplaced capitals.